# storing quick analytics using redis and node.js

Tags: node.js, redis, analytics

I am new to redis and would like to store the web analytic of web site globally and per user activity .

Below is what i am stuck with.

```
// to get all unique ips 

client.sadd('visitors',ip);  

// to records hits per ip

client.hincrby('hits',ip,1);
```

The above so far works fine and i do get number of different ips and hit counter per ip. 
the problem comes to store the activities made by each ip. i.e. Storing the link he clicked, searches he did, with datetime

Can some one please throw light on how to best manage it. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> the problem comes to store the activities made by each

You will need a separate structure for storing these.

The simplest rational structure is to have a *"list of actions by session"*. Take a look at the [sorted sets commands](http://redis.io/commands#sorted_set) which provide a basic framework for creating a list of actions within a session.

This will get you *something* quickly. However, this is probably not what you really want. In fact redis is probably not useful for this at all.

If you want to re-trace an entire site visit you really want to connect to some sort of true analytics framework. There are dozens of website tracking tools that provide this type of functionality, so it's not really clear that building one is very efficient.